# inserting zeros between the elements of vector with high performance and speed ( preferred to use STL)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, vector, mfc, gdal

I have extracted raster data of a `geotiff` image using `RasterIO` of the `GDAL library`. Since the image shown by `OpenGL` needs to have width and height both a multiple of 4, I have used this code after extracting the data.
the first `switch` block evaluates the rest of `RasterXSize(width)` divided by 4 and for example if it is 1, it means that we should add 3 columns meaning that we should add 3 zeros at the end of each row. This is done by the code:

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= RasterYSize; i++)
    pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.begin()+i*RasterXSize*depthOfPixel+(i-1)*3,3,0);
```

and the second `switch` block evaluates the rest of `RasterYSize(height)` divided by 4 and for example if it is 1, it means that we should easily add 3 rows to the end of the data which is done by this code:

```
pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.end(),3*RasterXSize,0);
```

This is the whole code that I have used for extracting the data and preparing it to be displayed by OpenGL:

```
void FilesWorkFlow::ReadRasterData(GDALDataset* poDataset)
{
    RasterXSize = poDataset -> GetRasterXSize();
    RasterYSize = poDataset -> GetRasterYSize();
    RasterCount = poDataset -> GetRasterCount();
    CPLErr error = CE_None;
    GDALRasterBand *poRasterBand; 
    poRasterBand = poDataset -> GetRasterBand(1);
    eType = poRasterBand -> GetRasterDataType();
    BytesPerPixel = GDALGetDataTypeSize(eType) / 8;
    depthOfPixel = RasterCount * BytesPerPixel;
    pRasterData.resize(RasterXSize * RasterYSize * RasterCount * BytesPerPixel);
    error = poDataset -> RasterIO(GF_Read,0,0,RasterXSize,RasterYSize,&pRasterData[0],RasterXSize,RasterYSize,eType,RasterCount,0,0,0,0);
    int modRasterXSize = RasterXSize % 4;
    switch (modRasterXSize)
    {
    case 1:
        {
         for ( int i = 1; i <= RasterYSize; i++)
            pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.begin()+i*RasterXSize*depthOfPixel+(i-1)*3,3,0);
        RasterXSize = RasterXSize+3;
        break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= RasterYSize; i++)
            pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.begin()+i*RasterXSize*depthOfPixel+(i-1)*2,2,0);
        RasterXSize = RasterXSize+2;
        break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
        for ( int i = 1; i <= RasterYSize; i++)
            pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.begin()+i*RasterXSize*depthOfPixel+(i-1)*1,1,0);
        RasterXSize = RasterXSize+1;
        break;
        }
    }
    int modRasterYSize = RasterYSize % 4;
    switch (modRasterYSize)
    {
    case 1:
        {
        pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.end(),3*RasterXSize,0);
        RasterYSize = RasterYSize+3;
        break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
        pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.end(),2*RasterXSize,0);
        RasterYSize = RasterYSize+2;
        break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
        pRasterData.insert(pRasterData.end(),1*RasterXSize,0);
        RasterYSize = RasterYSize+1;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

the first `switch` block is where my code gets slow and because I am working with a 16997*15931 image it takes a lot of time for the program to run through the for loop.
Note that `pRasterData` is a `member variable` of the class `FilesWorkFlow` and because of the problems I had in sending this variable to the [COpenGLControl class written by Brett Fowle in codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c10975/Setting-Up-OpenGL-in-an-MFC-Control.htm) and used by me in the [project with some slight changes](http://www.4shared.com/rar/EokGrA3R/InitialJobProject2.html), decided to use `vector<unsigned char>` instead of `unsighned char*`.
Now I am wondering is there anyway to implement these part of code faster using `vectors`?
Is there anyway to insert zero in certain parts of vector without using for loops and wasting too much time?
something like `std::transform`? I don't know!
Remember that I'm using `MFC` in `Visual Studio 2010` and it's better for me to use `STL` but if you have another suggestions besides using `vectors` or `STL`, I'd be glad to hear that?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is slow is because the members of the vector are getting moved multiple times.  Think about the members in the last row of your image.  They all have to be moved once for every row of the image.  It would be faster to create a whole new image, copying just the pixels you need from the original image and adding zeros where appropriate.

Here's an example:

```
void
  padColumns(
    std::vector<unsigned char> &old_image,
    size_t old_width,
    size_t new_width
  )
{
  size_t height = image.size() / old_width;
  assert(image.size() == old_width*height);

  std::vector<unsigned char> new_image(new_width * height);

  for (size_t row=0; row!=height; ++row) {
    std::copy(
      old_image.begin() + row*old_width,
      old_image.begin() + row*old_width + old_width,
      new_image.begin() + row*new_width
    );
    std::fill(
      new_image.begin() + row*new_width + old_width,
      new_image.begin() + row*new_width + new_width,
      0
    );
  }

  old_image = new_image;
}
```

Comment: thanks @vaughn Cato so you mean for example for the case that both RasterXSize and RasterYSize % 4 are 1, I should create a vector of size ((RasterXSize+3)*(RasterYSize+3)*depthOfpixel) and then copy members of pRasterData to it. Can this copying operation be done in a way faster than for loops just guide me with a keyword and I will search for more information on the web. thanks alot!